# Skip first and last x rows in CSV stored in SFTP using Azure Logic App

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which uses 2 Compose, the first one skips the first 3 rows

```
take(skip(variables('CSV Data'),3),sub(length(variables('CSV Data')),1))
```

and the second one skips the last 2 rows

```
take(outputs('Skip_Header'),sub(length(outputs('Skip_Header')),2))
```

This works great when I initialise the CSV Data Variable with an array

```
[
  "rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3",
  "blank1,blank2,blank3",
  "header1,header2,header3",
  "data1,data2,data3",
  "data4,data5,data6",
  "data7,data8,data9"
]
```

Below is my working Logic App definition:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "CSV Data",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3",
                                "blank1,blank2,blank3",
                                "header1,header2,header3",
                                "data1,data2,data3",
                                "data4,data5,data6",
                                "data7,data8,data9"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Skip_Footer": {
                "inputs": "@take(outputs('Skip_Header'),sub(length(outputs('Skip_Header')),2))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Skip_Header": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Skip_Header": {
                "inputs": "@take(skip(variables('CSV Data'),3),sub(length(variables('CSV Data')),1))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_CSV_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

However that was just for testing, because in reality the data is actually in a CSV format stored in a SFTP, so if I change the initialise variable from array

```
[
  "rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3",
  "blank1,blank2,blank3",
  "header1,header2,header3",
  "data1,data2,data3",
  "data4,data5,data6",
  "data7,data8,data9"
]
```

to string

```
rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3
blank1,blank2,blank3
header1,header2,header3
data1,data2,data3
data4,data5,data6
data7,data8,data9
```

Then that will a truer reflection of the actual scenario I have.  But what the Logic App does now is that only ignores the first 3 characters and last 2 characters instead of the first 3 rows and last 2 rows.  The new definition is below:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_CSV_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "CSV Data",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3\nblank1,blank2,blank3\nheader1,header2,header3\ndata1,data2,data3\ndata4,data5,data6\ndata7,data8,data9"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Skip_Footer": {
                "inputs": "@take(outputs('Skip_Header'),sub(length(outputs('Skip_Header')),2))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Skip_Header": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Skip_Header": {
                "inputs": "@take(skip(variables('CSV Data'),3),sub(length(variables('CSV Data')),1))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_CSV_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Screenshot below also shows the difference between the 2 Logic Apps, everything is the same except for "Initialize CSV Data":
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the same sample that you have provided, Im using 3 compose Connectors in order to skip the first Rows. Here is my Logic app

[image]

I'm using `Split To Get Rows` Connector in order to convert the csv file into Arrays. Below is the expression in it

```
split(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'),'

')
```

The above steps creates an extra empty array object In order to remove it Im using the next step `Rows Array` connector. Below is the expression in it

```
take(outputs('Split_To_Get_Rows'),sub(length(outputs('Split_To_Get_Rows')),1))
```

Going further In `Skip First Number of Rows` Connector is used to skip the first 3 rows. Here is the expression in it

```
take(skip(outputs('Rows_Array'),3),sub(length(outputs('Rows_Array')),1))
```

**Here is the Final Result:**

[image]

### UPDATED ANSWER

---

To remove x number of rows of footer then the expression would be

```
take(outputs('Skip_First_Number_Of_Rows_(Header)'),length(skip(outputs('Skip_First_Number_Of_Rows_(Header)'),0)))
```

Consider the below to be the array :-

```
[
rubbish1,rubbish2,rubbish3
blank1,blank2,blank3
header1,header2,header3
data1,data2,data3
sample1,sample2,sample3
data4,data5,data6
rubbish4,rubbish5,rubbish6
footer1,footer2,footer3
]
```

then here is the result for the mentioned expression

[image]

and if you need to skip 2 rows from below then the expression would be

```
take(outputs('Skip_First_Number_Of_Rows_(Header)'),length(skip(outputs('Skip_First_Number_Of_Rows_(Header)'),1)))
```

and here will be the result

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly if I initialise the variable array with the data described in the original question, but I get this error in the last connector when I actually get file content instead:
`Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose_3' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'take' parameters are out of range: 'count' must be a positive integer. The provided valus is '-1'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#take for usage details.'.`
Have noticed that the 2nd Connector is currently returning []

Comment: @tommyhmt Can you please add the actual data if possible because as per what initially the question asks I have given a solution to it else you can always create a new question adding the actual values and describing the error.

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda-MT, I have updated the question as that allows me to post screenshots for more clarity.  But it does seem like it works perfectly fine if I initialise the array variable with data, but fails if I open a CSV in SFTP and then load the variable with the content.

Comment: @tommyhmt The expression for the footer will be different when compared to the header. Please check the updated answer

Comment: @tommyhmt Also, Are you sending the CSV data from SFTP to `Initialize variable` connector?

Comment: Yeah I am, but I'm not able to post the Logic App definition because it won't save the SFTP connection details.  What I've done instead is updated the question to show that there is a difference when initialising the variable between array and string.  I believe when you first posted the solution it would work for an array, but since the CSV file in SFTP is a string then perhaps that's why it's not quite working.  I have posted the definitions of both the Logic Apps which should work for you but more importantly highlight what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks again